# Statistical Test to Compare Two Time-Series

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

I have eye-tracking recordings of a subject's gaze on a video, which I then used to calculate the distance from a specific point on the screen. The subject has viewed said video twice, and I'm interested in comparing the two time-series: the distance from point P in session A vs. distance from same point P in session B. (both time-series have the same recording-frequency).

Specifically, I want to know if there's a statistically significant difference between the 2 time-series, especially within a certain time-window (for example, everything in the light-blue area in the graph below).
I can either do it with the 2 series or with a single difference-based time-series (session A minus session B). I.e, if the difference is 0, the distance from point P is the same for session A and B (not that the distance is actually 0 and they're looking at point P, but the distance from P is the same).

What would be a good statistical test to show different viewing patterns of the two sessions?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a statistically significant difference?

Comment: I want to show the two viewing patterns are different, i.e seriesA and seriesB originate from two different populations.
One option I could think of is to calculate the area beneath the two lines and run a t-test. But that would mean "compressing" a lot of data into a single value, losing a lot of it's "richness". I was wondering if there are series-specific tests that I could use

Comment: If you want to check the difference in viewing patterns, you may check the cross-correlation. However, if you want to check they are from different populations, you may do the goodness of fit test. But it would be difficult to do the GoF test because your time series looks nonstationary.

Comment: Is it sufficient to test for a difference in mean?

Comment: Hey @kevin012 thanks, I took a quick look into what cross-correlation is and it looks like a good direction.

Comment: @RyanVolpi what do you mean? mean of the whole series?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to ask would it be good enough to show that the mean value of series one is significantly different from the mean value of series two?

Comment: @RyanVolpi well, it is interesting in and of itself, but that's easy to do (and has been done). Showing the means are sig-diff shows that the 2 series are not sampled from the same "series universe", but I want to show something even stronger - that the majority of points within each series is sig-diff from the equivalent point n the other on. Cross-correlation is a good direction